# How can accelerator and Magnetic Field type be extracted this way?

Tags: android, android-sensors, angle

I am make an app for my university project by measuring the tilt angle of the phone when a person holds it. I found this code for finding a phone's tilt angle.

How can `event.sensor.getType()` be 1 for accelerometer and 2 for Magnetic field at the same time? It is an integer value. This code always returns without executing since the `event.sensor.getType()` value is always 1. The code exists at **if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {**

I use a Nexus 4 phone with Android 5.0.1

Please tell me if I'm doing something wrong. I've registered the sensors in the prescribed way.

```
    float[] mGravity = null;
    float[] mGeomagnetic = null;
    float playerAngle1 = 0;
    float playerAngle2 = 0;

    **if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        mGravity = event.values;
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
        mGeomagnetic = event.values;**

    if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {

        float R[] = new float[9];
        float I[] = new float[9];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(mGravity[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(mGeomagnetic[i]);
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity,  mGeomagnetic);

        if (success) {

            System.out.println("getRotationMatrix");

            float orientation[] = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
            playerAngle1 = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(orientation[1], orientation[0]));
            playerAngle2 = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[1]);
            System.out.println("Angle1 :" + playerAngle1);
            System.out.println("Angle2 :" + playerAngle2);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a thought: Should I make the variables that collect the sensor data as static variables? That way whenever both are available, the angle can be measured.

Answer (score 0):

I had to store the accelerometer and magnetic field values as class variables and not local variables to get this working. Its a very simple change.